# Using ELK, I'm unsure how to use right filter in logstash config file for pairs

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a dollarVars term filled with things in this format...

Message 1:
Stuff1,Header1|Value1|Header2|Value2|Header3|Value3|

Message 2:
Stuff1,Header2|Value2|Header4|Value4|Header5|Value5|

Message 3:
Stuff1,Header3|Value3|Header4|Value4|Header5|Value5|

Etc.

My current filter looks like:

```
filter {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "message" => "%{stuff1},%{dollarVars}"
                 }
            }

    mutate {
    convert => {
      "stuff1"=>"integer"
                }
           }

     date{ 
      match => ["dateTime", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"]
         }
 }
```

What can I do to take my dissected dollarVars and break it up into the header with its respective value (the one to the right of each header)?

I suspect this would use the csv filter somehow using "|" instead of "," and somehow telling it each dollarVar odd column is a header and each even column goes with its respective (n-1) odd column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to split that dollarVars using [the split function within mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-split).

From there, I'd break out into ruby via the [ruby filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) to loop through the resultant split array and build out the new fields:

```
ruby {
  code => "
    i = 0
    while i < dollarVars.count
      event.set(dollarVars[i++]) = dollarVars[i++]
    end  
  "
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to use something simpler like:
     kv {
     csv{
     separator => "|"
     source => "dollarVars"
     }
     }

Answer (score 0):

Here is what fixed what I was trying to do. No mutate needed, just this ruby code.

```
   ruby { 
    code => "
    i = 0
    vars = event.get('dollarVars')
    v_array = vars.split('|')
    while i < v_array.count
      event.set(v_array[i],v_array[i+1])
      i += 2
    end  
  "
          }
```